# Connecting to netbeans's database

Tags: java, database, netbeans-8

I have already created a database using EasyPHP, but then I found out that I can create my database directly on NetBeans 8.2. The database that I created is a bit too big: it will take a time to recreate it. I didn't managed to import it in into NetBeans' database and I am having difficulty to connect to any database on NetBeans. I was wondering how can I import it into NetBeans' database and is it the same code that I used with EasyPHP (the one below) or should I change something?

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    new NotificationBuilder().withStyle(new DarkDefaultNotification()).withTitle("erreur")
    .withMessage("Erreur au niveau du driver").withDisplayTime(3000).showNotification();
}
try {
    con= DriverManager.getConnection(url,name,pwd);

} catch (SQLException e) {
    new NotificationBuilder().withStyle(new DarkDefaultNotification()).withTitle("erreur 2")
    .withMessage("erreur d'etablissement de connexion").withDisplayTime(3000).showNotification();

}
```

Comment: NetBeans is not a database system, it is an IDE that has some features to administer database. So please describe exactly what you did in NetBeans to create the database (and for which database system), otherwise your question is not really answerable.

Comment: in services you can find field named database where you can create a database and then create your tables execute SQL equerry  and others

Comment: And which options did you use?

Comment: i did not use any one i am not tying to create a table or database because i already created one in EASYPHP an i am trying to import it into this part (in netbeans)

Comment: In that case, it is entirely unclear to me what you're asking. You may want to consider rewriting and clarifying your question.